# How to close page in UIWebView and go back to app

Tags: ios, uiwebview

In my app by pressing a button I want to open `UIWebView` on full screen, the `UIWebView`  will load a HTML page that will hold a button that will close the `UIWebView` and return to app.

The problem is that I fail to make the button close the page and return to app.
I tried `parent.history.back()` and `history.back` and several versions of `self.close()` but nothing seems to  work (BTW it work in browser but not from `UIWebView`.

any idea?
thanks
-Z

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
[UIWebViewDelegate][1] has your answer

    - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request            
                                    navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
        if (request.URL == "SOME URL TO CLOSE WINDOW") {
            //do close window magic here!!
            [self stopLoading];
            return NO;
        }
        return YES;
    }
-(void)stopLoading{
    [_webView removeFromSuperview];
}

  [1]: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html
```

Answer (score 2):

> Updated for Swift 3:

If you want to close page of UIWebView and go back to app, use below of code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var mWebView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mWebView.delegate = self
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.loadWebView()
    }

    func loadWebView()  {
        mWebView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com/")!))
    }

    func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
        print("request: \(request.description)")
        if request.description == "https://stackoverflow.com/users/login"{
            //do close window magic here!!
            print("url matches...")
            stopLoading()
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

    func stopLoading() {
        mWebView.removeFromSuperview()
        self.moveToVC()
    }

    func moveToVC()  {
        print("Write code where you want to go in app")
        // Note: [you use push or present here]
        let vc = 
          self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
          "storyboardID") as! YourViewControllerName
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am wondering how can I do this with WKWebView, cause there is no request-based delegate method in WKWebView's delegates. so far I had no luck with webView methods!